# Determinant of the metric tensor

Tags: metric-spaces, tensor-products, coordinate-systems, tensors

How to calculate or simplify the determinant of the matrix formed by the coefficients of the metric tensor? Since,i am new to this chapter please keep the derivation upto the third dimension.

Comment: "New to this chapter"... cool but in what book?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through the permutations symbols:

$$ |g|=\frac{1}{3!}e^{ijk} e^{rst} g_{ir} g_{js} g_{kt}$$

Discussed in page-136 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor Calculus book

---

As pointed out by Peek-a-boo, this is indeed only true for 3-d

Comment: you should mention that this is only true in $3$ dimensions.